# What uniquely identifies an index in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table, information-schema, data-dictionary

Within the Oracle documentation, the (DBA|ALL)_INDEXES view has

`OWNER` The owner of the index

`INDEX_NAME` The name of the index

`TABLE_OWNER` The owner of the indexed object

`TABLE_NAME` The name of the indexed object

My question is what uniquely identifies the index?  Is it just `OWNER` and `INDEX_NAME`, or is it `OWNER`, `INDEX_NAME`, `TABLE_OWNER` and `TABLE_NAME`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index is uniquely identifed by its `INDEX_NAME` and its `OWNER` (ie the schema it belongs to). Basically, each object in a schema must have a unique name. Two different tables cannot have an index of the same name, unless these indexes belong to two different schemas.

Consider **[this simple example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0bbe9e5f8aa4807ccf5c146bf137cc8e)**:

```
create table mytable(id int, val int);
create index myindex on mytable(id);
-- ok

create table mytable2(id int);
create index myindex on mytable2(id);
-- ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```